# Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS freezes while booting from GRUB on HP Z2 Tower G9 Workstation Desktop PC

Tags: boot, grub2, 22.04, hp, freeze

I recently bought a new HP Z2 Tower G9 Workstation with a mind to install Ubuntu for better performance and less bloatware. However, despite apparently being [Ubuntu Certified](https://ubuntu.com/certified/202211-30819) for Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, it freezes while booting from GRUB.

I've already disabled Secure Boot, Fast Startup, and the Trusted Platform Module, but it still won't work. Removing `quick splash` from the boot command in GRUB shows that it freezes while or immediately after initializing the network driver with no error message. I'm not sure how to dump a full log to the USB I'm booting from but if anyone can tell me how, I'll post any and all relevant portions to ensure this gets fixed.

EDIT: Adding `nomodeset` to the boot command fixed it.

Comment: Is error from live installer or once installed? If you can mount /var/log in the install. Review log files
sudo grep -Ei 'warn|error' /var/log/*g But my system still outputs a page or more of errors. Some are just commands with error in description and many or not critical after looking each up with google. Often if system stops, its not last command posted but one several lines above. Do you have latest firmware for UEFI and if SSD for SSD? What video card/chip. Does booting recovery mode from grub menu work?

Answer (score 1):

Adding `nomodeset` to the boot command fixed it.